# fart' to mean I feel required to fart

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Does this statement sound right?

> 'I feel fart'

Does it mean 'to feel required to fart or to pass wind/gas."?

Comment: try: to have to do something.

Comment: You _feel gassy_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say like this instead:

> I need to fart.

Or to be polite:

> Excuse me, I need to use the restroom(US)/toilet(GB).

Comment: Note: in many situations it would not be polite to talk about needing to fart or go to the toilet.

Comment: ...and even less polite to actually fart.

Comment: "restroom" is exclusively American.  In the UK try "toilet".

Comment: @JamesK Thanks I don’t speak British so... I have updated my answer :)

Comment: You're really polite, @Jdrupal.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the answer is "no, that's not right", but to go into a bit more detail on why:

"I feel fart" is not a grammatically correct sentence.  The word "fart" can be either a verb ("to fart") or a noun ("a fart"), but you cannot use either a verb or a noun directly after "feel".  You would need to use an adjective instead (and "fart" is not an adjective).

Now, for many nouns, you can fairly easily convert them into adjectives for this sort of thing by adding "y" (or variations of it) to the end.  "Fart", however, is not one of those nouns that people generally do this with.  As noted in one of the comments, probably the closest adjective form to "fart" would be something like "gassy" (i.e. "having a lot of gas"), so you could say "I feel gassy", but this may not necessarily mean exactly what you want either, because saying "I feel <adjective>" usually implies that it is an enduring condition which applies to you in general (or at least over a certain period of time), not something specific to right now, so saying "I feel gassy" suggests this is a condition that's been going on for a while ("I've been feeling really gassy the past few days", etc)

If, however, you just want to express that you feel (at the moment) like something should or needs to happen, the construction you would generally want to use is "I feel like <sentence>":

> I feel like I need to fart.

Note, though, that in most cases for this specific sort of thing, people would usually just say:

> I need to fart.

(It's implied that the reason you know you need to is because you feel it).  One might put in the "I feel" part, though, if it was a situation where you knew (or suspected) that you didn't *actually* need to do it, but it felt like you did anyway.

Now, it should also be noted that while the last two sentences are perfectly correct English, culturally, the word "fart", is generally considered to be fairly rude/coarse language, and you shouldn't really use any forms of it in polite conversation (there are somewhat less crude phrases such as "pass gas", "pass wind", etc, but even they're often not suitable, since one generally shouldn't be talking about such body functions in polite conversation anyway).  If you're in that sort of situation, as @Jdrupal noted, it's usually better to simply excuse yourself (or if necessary, ask for the restroom/toilet), without actually explicitly talking about why.